# Nilpotent thickenings flat over the base

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, reference-request, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a Noetherian commutative ring, $A$ a flat $R$-algebra of finite type, $I\subset A$ an ideal such that $A/I$ is $R$-flat.

> For $n\ge 1$, is $A/I^n$ also $R$-flat?

In a similar vein, suppose $M$ is a finite $A$-module which is $R$-flat and consider the annihilator ideal $\text{Ann}_A(M)$ of $M$ in $A$.

> Is $A/\text{Ann}_A(M)$ flat over $R$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your first question is negative. Take $R=\mathbb{Z}$, consider $J=(2x,x^2)\subseteq\mathbb{Z}[x]$ and $A=\mathbb{Z}[x]/J$. Lastly, let $I=(x+J)\subseteq A$. Then $A/I\cong\mathbb{Z}$ is flat over $\mathbb{Z}$, but as $I^2=0$ we have $A/I^2\cong A$, which isn't flat, as it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}\oplus(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$ as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module.